# Can't figure out how to get CMake to pull in the correct headers for a custom clang driver

Tags: c++, msbuild, cmake, clang, llvm

CMake is giving me a real hard time, here. I checked out llvm, clang, and extras, and I created a custom driver folder, added it to the `llvm\tools\clang\tools\extra\CMakeLists.txt` and created my own CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
  Support
  )

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${LLVM_CONFIG})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")  

add_clang_executable(mydriver
  main.cpp
  )

set(CLANG_LIBS clangFrontend clangDriver clangSerialization clangParse
    clangCodeGen  clangSema clangAnalysis clangEdit clangAST clangLex
    clangBasic )

target_link_libraries(mydriver ${CLANG_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(mydriver ${LLVM_LIBS})
```

CMake works fine. I target VS2017 and build the `mydriver` project with msbuild

```
λ msbuild tools\clang\tools\extra\mydriver\mydriver.vcxproj
```

This results in the following error:

```
"C:\dev\llvm-build\tools\clang\tools\extra\mydriver\mydriver.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\dev\llvm\tools\clang\tools\extra\mydriver\main.cpp(45): error C2027: use of undefined type 'clang::Preprocessor Options' [C:\dev\llvm-build\tools\clang\tools\extra\mydriver\mydriver.vcxproj]
  C:\dev\llvm\tools\clang\tools\extra\mydriver\main.cpp(45): error C2228: left of '.addRemappedFile' must have class /struct/union [C:\dev\llvm-build\tools\clang\tools\extra\mydriver\mydriver.vcxproj]
  C:\dev\llvm\tools\clang\tools\extra\mydriver\main.cpp(50): error C2664: 'void clang::CompilerInstance::setInvocati on(std::shared_ptr<clang::CompilerInvocation>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'clang::CompilerInvocation *' to 'st d::shared_ptr<clang::CompilerInvocation>' [C:\dev\llvm-build\tools\clang\tools\extra\mydriver\mydriver.vcxproj]
```

However, `clangLex` is clearly included in the CLANG_LIBS variable in my CMakeLists.txt. The documentation of the `clang::PreprocessorOptions` class seems to indicate that I have the right libs included.

Any ideas?

Please note that this question is closely related to this one:
[Generate assembly from C code in memory using libclang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828480/generate-assembly-from-c-code-in-memory-using-libclang)

Answer (score 1):

In classic SO fashion, the problem was that the include file had migrated since the example was posted. The [clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PreprocessorOptions.html) requires a new header file, that is, in fact, in the include path. All I needed was:

```
#include <clang/Lex/PreprocessorOptions.h>
```

Sorry folks, nothing to see here.